# Preserve typed keys and values when transforming a const object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking for a solution to keep a `const` object intact while changing its shape dynamically.

If we take the following object (note it's a `as const`):

```js
const drinks = {
   cold: {
      juice: { 
          name: 'orange juice', 
          price: 2 
      },
      water: { 
          name: 'still water juice', 
          price: 0 
      },
   },
   warm: {
      coffee: { 
          name: 'coffee', 
          price: 1 
      },
      tea: { 
          name: 'earl gray', 
          price: 1 
      },
   }
} as const
```

and transform it dynamically like the following (types are omitted because this is what eventually this is what I'm looking for):

```js
const result = Object.entries(drinks).reduce(
    (result, [category, drinks]) => ({
        ...result,
        ...Object.entries(drinks).reduce(
            (mappedItems, [name, value]) => ({
                ...mappedItems,
                [name]: {
                    ...value,
                    category: category,
                },
            }),
            {},
        ),
    }),
    {},
)
```

we'll get the following result:

```js
{
    "juice": {
        "name": "orange juice",
        "price": 2,
        "category": "cold"
    },
    "water": {
        "name": "still water juice",
        "price": 0,
        "category": "cold"
    },
    "coffee": {
        "name": "coffee",
        "price": 1,
        "category": "warm"
    },
    "tea": {
        "name": "earl gray",
        "price": 1,
        "category": "warm"
    }
}
```

however the types are lost and we now have a `{ [key:string]: ... }`.
I'm looking for a way to preserve the exact typed keys and values from the initial `const`.

i.e. I'm looking to get the following union for the `keys` (`juice | water | coffee | tea`) as opposed to `string` - same for the respective values.

Comment: Type magic + assert: https://tsplay.dev/w2vVVw

Comment: this is awesome @kelsny. I'm curious, is it even possible to preserve the const types by typing the reducers or would a solution to this kind of problem always involve an `as` casting?

Comment: @kelsny This is indeed awesome, why don't you provide an answer around it?

Comment: You probably could, but in would clutter the runtime code a lot. I'd rather have a one-time assertion than a mess of a code with types scattered throughout (not to mention doing so would still require assertions here and there).

Comment: @kelsny agree but somewhat if we change the implementation of the reducer and/or introduce an error, TS won't tell us. In any case, please add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot easier to just assert that the result as the desired type (but check if it works correctly at runtime, too).

```
const result = Object.entries(drinks).reduce(
  (result, [category, drinks]) => ({
    ...result,
    ...Object.entries(drinks).reduce(
      (mappedItems, [name, value]) => ({
        ...mappedItems,
        [name]: {
          ...value,
          category: category,
        },
      }),
      {},
    ),
  }),
  {},
) as Transform<typeof drinks>;
```

But we still have to get the correct type somehow from `drinks`. This is a little hard to digest but it's basically extracting the drinks from the categories and adding the category to them:

```
  {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      [P in keyof T[K]]: T[K][P] & { category: K };
    };
  }[keyof T]
```

However, this gives us a union, and we need to intersect everything in the union together, so we use the utility from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type):

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I,
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Transform<T> = UnionToIntersection<
  {
    [K in keyof T]: {
      [P in keyof T[K]]: T[K][P] & { category: K };
    };
  }[keyof T]
>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgJwJZgNYRgXhgbwLABQMMoANnAFy6HHEBWArksAKZX5G3FgCGAtmxgAiEAh5gA5ixiNmLIQBoaXGAAdkrKgCYlnYgF9dXAO48oLBO2VdeAqkOhJSpGKfMIZTVouu11cqgAGI1pDZTDOUwQ+Kz0SEAAzBJZBDhUYW0EhUCSUnzjif00YAEYQg3KYcx5Y9Mz7Fh4EFwkxAE989KLBMt8IisJ9GB4MUEgoAG5CQig21WkAVTAkcAAVEABJMHcIFmAoFbAAHgWAPiwYAAoFmBYAD3MwOAxxNpgAfivUKgWASixzgA3EBIOAwKhgFiAiz-e6PZ5XZTfGAoZIeDa6f6YIEguDKT4bZQQqEWKYEGZzaSrMSQBKiPhHVbnbBLQ7rLY7PYHcBHZRpWgAbQA0iiwDBUCw2okYKsALq1FQCgAKovFkulq2FsvlMq1ytlMAAZLgSGYWBJRG0qCL9GSuLbwgKJVKEjLZYRTmTCGNoDAECwIAxSLBsAB5ABGdC5ADoWNtkAHLogUOhftH-XAGKxLspLv7A8GFDABcAzRaEG0i8m0BBZVjzpd+cRoy380GoJUW9GI1H9rH40hE9XU+mWJns75iJc+DxVPM4BtzHwIEWBZki4CeKQGCw6wCrk2VF2Z3Ox4uWMvKlw1-xdwr0s2W5vtywrypS+Zy1bTZ-LW+BgUMD6L8b44P0tAgeEkGcGBmLDBg1LiBAdLREcszzNKw4QJ6hBAA)